# Is there a possible way that humans could experience rapid physical transformation into something more animalistic?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

Physical transformation relies on evolution, which typically works n the scale of millions of years and in accordance with environmental needs.

However, is there any plausible way maybe through the implementation of some kind of biological vector (fungi, virus or parasite) that a human being can rapidly experience physical transformations over a MUCH smaller time scale? I'm talking a week or two.

The transformations would be predatory - enhancing smell and hearing, sharpened teeth, higher pain threshold, fear of fire etc. Almost vampiric and/or werewolf like tendencies.

What could bring about such changes to people within a tiny span of time? I would assume it would have to likely be something engineered?

Comment: Could you be more specific about a list of what you want? Some of these can be done in seconds (pain threshhold) , others would take quite a lot longer (sharpened teeth).

Comment: This is a common approach I've encountered: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Lightning_(cider)

Answer (score 3):

Something along those lines might be possible with a combination of hormones that activate previously dormant genes, and activation of stem cells to accelerate building of new tissue.

Both could be delivered by injections or a biological vector. It will not be pleasant for the person, and might kill them.

We know steroid hormones are (ab)used to enhance muscle growth. But they require exercise and eating lots of protein. So you'd need to make the person restless/energetic, and make them hungry for protein.

Enhanced senses could probably be achieved by increasing nerve function.

Comment: "So you'd need to make the person restless/energetic, and make them hungry for protein." ...because those traits are *never* possessed by werewolves . Okay, usually the transformation happens *first*, but it's still cool that you just rationalized stereotypical werewolf behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy, as long as you are not asking for superhuman abilities, like faster running speed, superhuman strength, claws, etc.

The things like enhancing smell and hearing, higher pain threshold and fear of fire, does not require any physical changes. Its all in our brain.

Have you heard, that someone who lost his sight, becomes sensitive to sounds and smell? Not because they got a new pair of ears or nose, but because their brain starts spending more processing power on these things.

So, Imagine a kind of parasite like [Ophiocordyceps unilateralis](https://www.newsweek.com/parasite-zombie-ants-hijacks-bodies-not-brains-707816), that may enter one's brain, through water or insect bites, and grows there for a few hours and causes the brain to have these changes.

Changes like enhancing smell and hearing, higher pain threshold and fear of fire can be immediate, even slight increase in strength and speed can be immediate because any normal human can produce higher strength when under adrenaline rush, while physical changes like sharper teeth, longer nails and hair and major muscle changes can also be there but will require a few days.